# Perfino server running out of memory daily

Tags: perfino

We've been running Perfino on non-prod hosts successfully for the past year.

Recently we added 9 new DEV hosts and now the Perfino service is running out of memory and crashing every day.

We've thrown absurd amounts of memory at the Perfino service but it doesn't seem to help.

It's currently monitoring 955 VMs across 11 hosts.

Ideas on how to proceed?

Many thanks,
David

Comment: Did you reduce the retention settings in the general settings to the minimum? Do you produce a lot of different transaction names in the CPU views or different payload names in the probe payloads (like SQL statements)?

Comment: Yes we reduced the retention settings to the minimum. There are many transaction and payload names.

Comment: I'm trying to hook the service up to a profiler to get a better understanding of what's happening but there are fireball rules in place that are making this difficult. Is it possible to pass the agent to the perfino service so that it can monitor itself?

Comment: You can use the bin/jpdump command line utility in JProfiler (no license required) to get an HPROF snapshot from a running perfino instance. You can then send a download link to support@ej-technologies.com and we will have a look at it.

Comment: It turns out that heap usage is stable at about 3.5GB but we seem to be running out of threads?

In just over an hour we went from 1010 to 7730 threads. I think it's likely that this is taking out the server and not heap memory.

I'll get you thread and HPROF dumps.